# Is there a flag/setting to enable java String intern automatically?

Tags: java, string, performance

Is there a JVM level setting or library that can enable String intern automatically. Like when a String is SHORTER than 100, then call intern method for String instance automatically.

I want this feature because for some services, it is hard to find a unified entrance and call String.intern when a String instance is created.

The service creates too many instances (with 4G young gen size, young gc is triggered every 5 secs) and seems this is bottleneck for performance. So I want to try to use String intern to reduce String instance creation.

Comment: You should almost never intern strings manually. Interning all long strings would be catastrophic if you're doing any sort of I/O or debugging.

Comment: What benefit do you expect automatic interning to have?  Code has to be written specifically to take advantage of interned strings (comparing using `==` instead of `equals`), and code that's written specifically for interning can just call the `intern` method when appropriate.  Interning won't make a difference (except maybe slightly better cache utilization) for things that compare strings using `equals`.

Comment: 'for some services, it is hard to find a unified entrance and call String.intern when a String instance is created' why? What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry for not describing this well. Generally speaking, I want to reduce String instance creation because there are lots of duplicated Strings. And expecting to improve performance. The service is a typical DB related service, read and write data from/to DB. Data from same column are very likely to be the same.